# 90s YA fantasy series where a warrior meets a sorceress and they travel together

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, choose-your-own-adventure

There may only be two books in the series, one is a regular novel and the other is a choose-your-own-adventure type gamebook. I read them in 1997 so I assume they were written in the 90s, 80s or even 70s. I found them in my school's library on the same shelf as *The Adventures of Goldhawk* but I don't recall them being illustrated.

The regular novel was a fantasy story about a warrior meeting a young sorceress while travelling, and they began travelling together.

The gamebook was set after the regular novel and was about the warrior, sorceress and I think two other characters fighting their way through a castle or tower. I recall it being quite long for a gamebook compared to the Goldhawk series.

Answer (score 3):

IF the sorceress was replaced with [a male magic-user](https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Sallazar) for the gamebook, then I think the novel was [*Firestorm*](https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Firestorm), book 1 of a 4-part series called [*"The Zagor Chronicles"*](https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/The_Zagor_Chronicles). The first two books in the series were published in 1993, and the second two in 1994, so the dates are consistent with you finding them in the late 90s.

[image]

That would mean that the gamebook was [*Legend of Zagor*](https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Legend_of_Zagor_(book)), published in 1993. It was a very late entry in the [*Fighting Fantasy*](https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Fighting_Fantasy) series of gamebooks.

[image: Original cover art] [image]

[image]

The "castle or tower" you remember them fighting their way through was called ["Castle Argent"](https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Castle_Argent) and the picture at the wiki link shows it to be primarily composed of a large tower.

According to the Fighting Fantasy wiki, the warrior, [Braxus](https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Braxus) meets the sorceress, Jallarial early in book 1, and they travel together. The wiki doesn't have a page for Jallarial, annoyingly, so I'm working with incomplete information here.

The other two characters in [the gamebook](https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Legend_of_Zagor_(book)) were [Anvar the Barbarian](https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Anvar_(Amarillia)) and Stubble the Dwarf, who also has no wiki page dedicated to him. Stubble and Anvar also featured in the novels, and if I understand Anvar's wiki entry correctly, they meet up early on in *Firestorm* but don't encounter Braxus and Jallarial until later in the book.

If this is the correct answer, then I should note that although the four main characters work as a team in the novels, only one of them enters Castle Argent in the gamebook (You choose which one.) Also, Jallarial is replaced with a male wizard, her brother [Sallazar](https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Sallazar).

The gamebook was indeed set after the novel. Remember, *Firestorm* was book 1 in the series. Book 2, [*Darkthrone*](https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Darkthrone), was an alternate version of the gamebook's story.

I did read some of the Zagor Chronicles, but I wasn't really a fan, so I'm afraid I've forgotten quite a bit of this. I loved the Fighting Fantasy gamebooks, but the novelisations never did much for me. I can say that I don't remember the novels having illustrations, but I know the gamebook did have some.

There's a very interesting Amazon review of *Firestorm* at [this link.](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R20Y7X99YIHNI5/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0140368647)

The fact that you found these books on the same shelf as *The Adventures of Goldhawk* is no surprise. *Goldhawk* was a spin-off of the *Fighting Fantasy* series, targeted at younger readers - which would explain why it was so much shorter than *Legend of Zagor*! The FF wiki doesn't have much on *Goldhawk*, but see [this page](https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Darkmoon%27s_Curse). Even more relevant to the library shelf:

- The *Goldhawk* books were written by [Ian Livingstone](https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Ian_Livingstone).
- The *Zagor Chronicles* were written by Ian Livingstone and [Carl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Sargent) [Sargent](https://fightingfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Carl_Sargent) (aka Keith Martin).
- The cover of *Legend of Zagor* credited Ian Livingstone as the author, even though it was written by Carl Sargent.

So *all* of these books would have been in the same location under 'L' on an alpabetically-ordered library shelf!